# Checkout address custom attributes don't get rendered in address information components

Tags: checkout, knockoutjs, custom-attributes, magento2.3.3, customer-address

I have to add a new customer address attribute `apellido2`, this field is a second last name and must be present in both shipping and billing address. So I after reading a few posts, I started with my custom module:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="apellido2" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="apellido2_layoutProcessors" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Plugin/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout;


class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        $customerData = $customerObj->getCustomer();
        $customerApellido2 = (isset($customerData['apellido2']) && !empty($customerData['apellido2'])) ? $customerData['apellido2'] : '' ;

        // Apellido 2 visile in shipping address form
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['apellido2'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                // customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)
                'customScope' => 'billingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'customEntry' => null,
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                'id' => 'segundo',
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.apellido2',
            'label' => 'Segundo Apellido',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [
                'required-entry' => true,
            ],
            'sortOrder' => 41,
            'id' => 'segundo',
            'options' => [],
            'value' => $customerApellido2
        ];

        // Apellido 2 visile in billing-address-form: Loop all payment methods (because billing address is appended to the payments)
        $configuration = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];
        foreach ($configuration as $paymentGroup => $groupConfig) {
            if (isset($groupConfig['component']) and $groupConfig['component'] === 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address') {

                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentGroup]['children']['form-fields']
                ['children']['apellido2'] = [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        // customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)
                        'customScope' => 'billingAddress.custom_attributes',
                        'customEntry' => null,
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                        'id' => 'segundo',
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => $groupConfig['dataScopePrefix'] . 'custom_attributes' . '.apellido2',
                    'label' => __('Segundo Apellido'),
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'validation' => [
                        'required-entry' => true,
                        'min_text_length' => 0,
                    ],
                    'sortOrder' => 41,
                    'id' => 'segundo',
                    'value' => $customerApellido2
                ];
            }
        }


        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

I also developed a JS mixin to poupulate customAtributes:

**/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```js
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-billing-address': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/action/set-billing-address': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-billing-address.js**

```js
define([
  'jquery',
  'mage/utils/wrapper',
  'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setBillingAddressAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(setBillingAddressAction, function (originalAction, messageContainer) {

            var billingAddress = quote.billingAddress();

            if (billingAddress != undefined) {

                if (billingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                    billingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
                }

                if (billingAddress.customAttributes != undefined) {
                    $.each(billingAddress.customAttributes, function (key, value) {

                        if ($.isPlainObject(value)) {
                            value = value['value'];
                            key = this.attribute_code;
                        }

                        billingAddress['customAttributes'][key] = value;
                        billingAddress['extension_attributes'][key] = value;
                    });
                }

            }

            return originalAction(messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

In My account, the customer can set their custom attribute without problems and it's stored and shown.

Then in checkout, custom attribute is not present. So i had to modify html templates to render it properly:

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html**

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="shipping-address-item 1v" css="'selected-item' : isSelected() , 'not-selected-item':!isSelected()">
    <text args="address().prefix"/> <text args="address().firstname"/> <text args="address().middlename"/>
    <text args="address().lastname"/>
    <if args="address().customAttributes['apellido2']">
        <text args="address().customAttributes['apellido2'].value"/>
    </if>
    <if args="address().customAttributes[0]">
        <!-- ko foreach: address().customAttributes -->
            <!-- ko if: attribute_code == "apellido2"-->
                <text args="value"/>
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </if>
    <text args="address().suffix"/><br/>
    <text args="_.values(address().street).join(', ')"/><br/>
    <text args="address().city "/>, <span text="address().region"></span> <text args="address().postcode"/><br/>
    <text args="getCountryName(address().countryId)"/><br/>
    <a if="address().telephone" attr="'href': 'tel:' + address().telephone" text="address().telephone"></a><br/>

    <button visible="address().isEditable()" type="button"
            class="action edit-address-link"
            click="editAddress">
        <span translate="'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- ko if: (!isSelected()) -->
    <button type="button" click="selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item">
        <span translate="'Ship Here'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/billing-address/details.html**

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div data-bind="text: ko.computed(function() { debugger; })"></div>
<div if="isAddressDetailsVisible() && currentBillingAddress()" class="billing-address-details">
    <text args="currentBillingAddress().prefix" /> <text args="currentBillingAddress().firstname" />
    <text args="currentBillingAddress().middlename" />
    <text args="currentBillingAddress().lastname" /> <text args="currentBillingAddress().suffix" />
    <text args="currentBillingAddress().customAttributes.apellido2.value" />

    <each args="data: currentBillingAddress().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
        <if args="typeof element === 'object'">
            <if args="element.label">
                <text args="element.label" />
            </if>
            <ifnot args="element.label">
                <if args="element.value">
                    <text args="element.value" />
                </if>
            </ifnot>
        </if>
        <if args="typeof element === 'string'">
            <text args="element" />
        </if><br />
    </each>
    <br />
    <text args="_.values(currentBillingAddress().street).join(', ')" /><br />
    <text args="currentBillingAddress().city " />, <span text="currentBillingAddress().region"></span> <text
        args="currentBillingAddress().postcode" /><br />
    <text args="getCountryName(currentBillingAddress().countryId)" /><br />
    <a if="currentBillingAddress().telephone" attr="'href': 'tel:' + currentBillingAddress().telephone"
        text="currentBillingAddress().telephone"></a><br />

    <button visible="!isAddressSameAsShipping()" type="button" class="action action-edit-address" click="editAddress">
        <span translate="'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Overwriting this two templates make my attribute visible.
In shipping address:
[image]

In billing address:
[image]

The issue arises trying to create a new address during the checkout process. My custom field is shown and validated in the form:

[image]

But, clicking into "Update Address" raises a js error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return currentBillingAddress().customAttributes.apellido2.value }"
Message: Cannot read property 'apellido2' of undefined
    at text (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:1), <anonymous>:3:104)
    at update (knockout.js:4659)
    at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3373)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2173)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2140)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:2101)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1954)
    at knockout.js:3371
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:159)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:3343)
```

[image]

My custom attribute is not available anymore. The knockout context shows that customAttributes are empty:

```
"currentBillingAddress":
canUseForBilling: ƒ ()
city: "New City"
company: ""
countryId: "ES"
customAttributes: undefined
customerId: undefined
email: undefined
fax: undefined
firstname: "Antonio"
getCacheKey: ƒ ()
getKey: ƒ ()
getType: ƒ ()
isDefaultBilling: ƒ ()
isDefaultShipping: ƒ ()
isEditable: ƒ ()
lastname: "Carrión"
middlename: undefined
postcode: "30001"
prefix: undefined
region: "A Coruña"
regionCode: "A Coruсa"
regionId: "391"
saveInAddressBook: 1
street: ["New address"]
suffix: undefined
telephone: "666666666"
vatId: ""
```

so my call to `<text args="currentBillingAddress().customAttributes.apellido2.value" />` fails because of being undefined.

So my question: how can I make customAttributes available in checkout when I try to add a new address? I read several posts here and can't figure how to fix it. On the other hand, I can't understand how default Magento templates don't show customAttributes. What am I missing?

I'm using **Magento 2.3.3**

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance